# Removing the salt of passwords

Tags: security, bcrypt

I made a web application that is growing slowly, but already have a bit of an user base, and when I first created the code of the authentification and registration system I decided to salt the password with an environment value. Today I'm starting to see that the salt is unecessary since I'm using bcrypt and bcrypt already have a salting system. So I want to remove the salt from the password

The way I imagine to do this would be to update the production code with a migration to the database adding a `isPasswordSalted` column to each user (default to true), and next time they log in, the salt will be removed from their password (by comparing salted password with hash, if that's the same, hash the unsalted clear password and updated the database)

The "problem" is that I don't really want to create a column in the table that only use is to remember if the password is salted or not. That's seems pretty unecesarry

So I wondered if the following was safe:

```js
const salted = process.env.SALT + req.body.password;
if (bcrypt.compareSync(salted, user.password) {
   // Replacing user.password with unsalted password
   user.password = bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 12);
} else if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password) {
   // Authentification is alreayd ok since req.body.password is already correct
} else {
   // Bad authentification
}
```

Or if this code could create some problems (like this create 2 chances for an attacker to guess the password)

Comment: Note that the point of salt is to slow down the extraction of plaintext passwords once attackers have the DB - if all values had the _same_ salt that would be pointless. What you had with the env var was closer to [pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography)).

Comment: No need for a flag column. Compare the password with the unsalted version. If it matches you're done. If not, compare it with the salted version. If it matches, create and store the unsalted hash and you're done. If neither matches, it's the wrong password.

Comment: Ok I didn't knew about pepper, I though this was helpful at the beggining (then I learned that bcrypt already made salting different for each users) thanks for the ressources

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular that's exactly the thing I wondered, I wondered if that was safe to make something like this or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the technical point of view such code it is like allowing the user to test with a single password two possible hashes which is not good from the statistical point of view.
I understand that using an additional column to know if a password is salted might seem redundant. However, it would be much safer. If you are worried about the extra space occupied by that column you could add a simple check in your web application to periodically check if there are no more rows with the old salt and if so you can delete such row.